# How to make a service application in Firefox OS?

Tags: firefox-os, service-application

I need a service application in Firefox OS which should start at boot time. I searched several sites but didn't get anything useful. Also I would like to know what all changes should be made in the manifest file and js file. Also the requirement of index.html file.

Comment: I'm not sure you're able to do it with an app. You might have to change Gecko itself. I'm saying that, because with apps you don't have permission to do that without creating a certified app. And even if you manage to create a certified app, I'm not sure you'll be able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Background Services](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/API_support_table), but it's not available yet, and tagged a certified app right now. So it's not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The most relevant API that could act as 'service' is [alarm API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/AlarmAPI), which allow app to trigger itself periodically and do some stat checking. Calendar/Email App use that technique to pull new event/mail from internet.

Ref: [http://tech.mozilla.com.tw/posts/2223](http://tech.mozilla.com.tw/posts/2223/%E8%B5%B7%E5%BA%8A%E5%9B%89%EF%BC%81%E6%88%91%E7%9A%84%E6%89%8B%E6%A9%9F%E5%AF%B6%E8%B2%9D%EF%BC%81-alarm-api-%E7%9A%84%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E8%88%87%E4%BB%8B%E7%B4%B9)